# Comparing a string to text

Tags: c++, string, compare

When I attempt this:

```
string msm_arg1;
```

...

```
if (msm_arg1 = "--console" )
run_console();
```

I get:

```
res/functions/ReadArgs.h|40|error: could not convert ‘msm_arg1.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator= [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>](((const char*)"-c"))’ from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘bool’|
```

What I'm seeing is that it is trying to compare a string (msm_arg1) to a bool, which "--console" clearly isn't.

I can see one possible way around: creating a string to compare to, but with plently of possible CLI arguments, that could become messy.

I am using Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 11:10 with the default gcc.

Comment: -1: basic reference question. Your C++ book has a section on operators, I'm sure.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: If he has a book, that is. :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: He must absolutely have a book before resorting to asking for free help!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I absolutely agree. But, apparently, many do not :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I make an outspoken assumption in my comments that they do, to _really_ hammer the point home if they do not :) ("What do you mean you _don't have a book_?!?!")

Comment: I do have a book (cplusplus.com's PDF). The reason I asked was because I couldn't understand what the error message was saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator.

At present, your code does this:

```
   if (msm_arg1 = "--console")
//     \____________________/
//       assign to msm_arg1;
//      evaluate to new value
// 
   if (msm_arg1)
//     \______/
//      convert string to bool
//       for `if` comparison
//
// ERROR: Can't do that!
```

The *equivalence operator* in C++ is `==`:

```
if (msm_arg1 == "--console")
```

---

Also it's worth being aware that this is a case-sensitive comparison, and that it won't work properly at all if you stop using `std::string` and attempt to compare two literals.

Comment: Thanks! I was up late last night, so that's probably why I did that!

Comment: @NRoach44: Pas de probleme :)